# Connect/webhook payload contains wrong recipient Sent date

Tags: docusignapi

My DocuSign REST connector receives some Connect/webhook payload where the "Sent" node in RecipientStatus node contains a wrong date: 0001-01-01T00:00:00

It happens when these conditions are filled:

- Connect 1.0
- A CustomField has been added using "EnvelopeRecipients : update" DocuSign API. The payload sent contains for each participant to update only the recipientId and the CustomFields
- sign Order is activated

For participants at "created" status (only the 1st signer is at "sent" status), the "Sent" node should not exist but here it exists with a wrong date "0001-01-01T00:00:00"

Does someone know how this issue would be fixed?

Thank you for your help

Comment: We can't answer this with the information provided. I would recommend either:
1. Contact customer support and work with them
2. Upgrade to using Connect 2.0 and see if the issue is still there